How to deploy an iOS project to my iPad without an Apple Developer account?
I am new to Xcode. I am running Xcode 15 and whatever the current version of Swift is.
I am developing a small app for personal use which I have no intention of deploying, I just want to run it on My iPad. I tried to follow the steps in several previous posts, but each time the process wanted me to sign up for an Apple Developer account. I do not want to pay Apple an annual subscription for a personal project. Is there a way that I can just compile my App and move it to my iPad without involving Apple?

Deploying it to your own device requires an account, however, you can sign up for free (you need to be al least 16, I suppose). Then you can download it on your iPad, without having to pay fees. Simply go to xCode settings, accounts and create one.

Thank you I am well past 16, I am 65 in a few weeks.  :-)

@JamesMartin Wow! That's cool!

You can test your apps on devices for free, as written in Choosing a Membership:

Who should enroll
You can learn how to develop apps for Apple platforms for free without enrolling. With just an Apple ID, you can
access Xcode, software downloads, documentation, sample code, forums,
and Feedback Assistant, as well as test your apps on devices. ...

The document has a table which shows also that
you can do "On-device testing" for free, if you Sign In with Your Apple ID:

Benefits and resources



 
Sign In with Your Apple ID
Apple Developer Program




Xcode developer tools
●
●


Xcode beta releases
●
●


On-device testing
●
●


  ⋮
  ⋮
  ⋮


Cost
Free
99 USD




However, below the table, there are notes:

If you’re signing in to Xcode with an Apple ID that’s not affiliated
with the Apple Developer Program, you’ll be able to perform on-device
testing for personal use (Xcode refers to this as a Personal Team).
However, there are some limitations to this type of development
workflow that require you to re-provision the app to your device
periodically, such as:

The number of App IDs that can be registered your account at one time is limited to 10 and each expires after 7 days.
The number of test devices that can be registered to your account for each platform is limited to 3 and each expires after 7 days.
Provisioning profiles will expire 7 days from issuance, which may require you to rebuild and re-install your app to your device after
expiration.


